# Getting empty rows in mysql when entering data into database from JSON post to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json

I am using JSON with POST method to PHP, I am able to display values in the Xcode, but the values are not being displayed in mySql. It is displaying empty rows.I think my PHP code might be missing some part. Please  help me out.

My Xcode code

```
- (IBAction)uploadData:(id)sender {

        NSDictionary *loginDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   self.shipmentID.text, @"name",

                                  nil];




        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:loginDict
                                                           options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                            error:&error];

        if (! jsonData) {
            NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       // NSString *jsonString=@"{"username":"root","password":""}";
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=%@", jsonString];
                //NSLog(@"fweffwr %@" , jsonString);
                NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/~robot/post.php"]];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

                [request setHTTPBody:postData];
            NSLog(@"checking %@",post);
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
               // [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
            [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        }

    }
```

My PHP code

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","PalletApp");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Success";
    }

    $json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
    echo "JSON: \n";
    echo "--------------\n";
    var_dump($json);
    echo "\n\n";

    $data = json_decode($json);
    echo "Array: \n";
    echo "--------------\n";
    var_dump($data);
    echo "\n\n";

    $name = $data->name;

    echo "Result: \n";
    echo "--------------\n";
    echo "Name     : ".$name; 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sample values('$name')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What are fields in table `sample`, possibly you are trying to enter data to a wrong field

Comment: have you tried to echo `$name` and see if there is value ?

Comment: There is only one field in sample database and if we give echo , I am confused on where it will be displayed. It works fine if we hard code the value for $name.

Comment: what does `var_dump($json)` prints ?

Comment: I am new to PHP, I do not know where the PHP echo values are printed.

Answer (score 0):

When writing insert query, always try to specify the field names.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$sql = "INSERT INTO sample(`field_name`) values('$name')";
```

Also use [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to safely insert the date to mysql.

Comment: I tried that and it did not show up anything. The rows are not added as well when I try that.

Comment: `field_name` should be the name of your mysql tables field. Please let me knwo how many fields do you have for the table `sample`

Comment: I have only one field in my sample database, i tried field_name with my mysql tables field but I could not print the data.

Comment: Try using mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: I tried mysql_real_escape_string as well but its still not showing the data in mysql. Instead of $name = $data->name; i have tried for example $name='999', then this value is displayed in mysql. I think the problem might be with $data->name.